# Problem with SPARQLWrapper (Python)

Tags: python, rdf, sparql

I'm making a SPARQL query against the Sesame store in localhost, using [SPARQLWrapper](http://sparql-wrapper.sourceforge.net/):

```
  sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/rep/statements')
  sparql.setQuery(query)
  sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
  results = sparql.query().convert()
```

However, I'm getting:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 339, in query
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 318, in _query
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable
```

The strange thing is, however, that querying against the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint everything works fine...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For SPARQLWrapper you don't normally have to add the `statements` bit in the URI. I.e., this should work:

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/rep')
```

And then just continue with the rest of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the problem by doing the SPARQL wrapping myself...

Comment: Why don't you say how and/or point to the code so the next person can see the answer.

Comment: Or, better yet, fix SPARQLWrapper, it's pretty readable and easy to hack. SPARQLWrapper has a mailing list, and its developers are open to fixes and suggestions: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/sparql-wrapper-devel

Comment: wrong reading sesame workbench documentation, wrong reporting issues, wrong providing feedback... wrong user in the end, I do not know why we should care